# std::filesystem copy_file failure

Tags: c++, windows, std-filesystem

I am trying to make a copy of a file.

This code runs without error, but the copied file is incomplete:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    error_code ec;
    filesystem::copy_file(
        "C:/ProgramData/spectronix/oximeter/spectrumalpha.dat",
        "C:/ProgramData/spectronix/oximeter/test.dat", ec );
    cout << ec.value() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

sample run:

```
C:\ProgramData\spectronix\oximeter>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 86AE-5DBA

 Directory of C:\ProgramData\spectronix\oximeter

2020-04-03  04:36 PM    <DIR>          .
2020-04-03  04:36 PM    <DIR>          ..
2020-04-03  01:29 PM            24,576 spectrum.dat
2020-03-23  12:27 PM           131,072 spectrumalpha.dat
2020-04-03  04:36 PM           963,072 test.exe
               3 File(s)      1,118,720 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  823,148,593,152 bytes free

C:\ProgramData\spectronix\oximeter>test
0

C:\ProgramData\spectronix\oximeter>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 86AE-5DBA

 Directory of C:\ProgramData\spectronix\oximeter

2020-04-03  04:37 PM    <DIR>          .
2020-04-03  04:37 PM    <DIR>          ..
2020-04-03  01:29 PM            24,576 spectrum.dat
2020-03-23  12:27 PM           131,072 spectrumalpha.dat
2020-04-03  04:37 PM             7,409 test.dat
2020-04-03  04:36 PM           963,072 test.exe
               4 File(s)      1,126,129 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  823,148,515,328 bytes free
```

Notice that the original file has 131,072 bytes, but the copied file only has 7,409 bytes.

Comment: You are clearly running the code on Windows. Do you have the same problem using the Win32 [`CopyFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile) function instead?

Comment: No, that seems to work

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc v8.3 .........

Comment: This looks like  the copy-a-binary-file-as-text problem (where the first EOF character ends the copy), but `copy_file` isn't supposed to care about that.

Comment: You should try updating your compiler or using the visual studio compiler, the mingw compiler seems to have a few issues with std::filesystem on Windows